# Label error in Mariesim, Any advice on how to fix it?

Tags: marie

I am having an issue in Marie where it is saying that the error is " A label cannot have 0..9 as its beginning character". How would I go about fixing this?
The image below is the section of code where this error appears. I have never seen this before and my friends nor me can find anything on it. Any advice is appreciated!

```
   START,     INPUT
   SKIPCOND   800
   HALT
   OUTPUT
   STORE       A
   SUB         Z
   SKIPCOND    800
   SKIPCOND    000
   JUMP        START
   X,          INPUT
   STORE       B
   OUTPUT   
   SUB         A
   SKIPCOND    800
   JUMP        Y
   JUMP        X
   Y,          LOAD    B
   ADD         C
   STORE       S
   EVEN,       SUB     T
   SKIPCOND    800
   JUMP        L
   JUMP        EVEN
   L,          SKIPCOND 400
   JNS         ODD
   LOAD        S
   OUTPUT
   LOAD        A
   SUB         S
   STORE       N
   OUTPUT
   JUMP        START
   ODD,        OUTPUT    S
   LOAD        S
   ADD         0
   STORE       S
   JUMPI       ODD
   A,          DEC      00
   B,          DEC      00
   S,          DEC      00
   N,          DEC      04
   C,          DEC      04
   Z,          DEC      94
   T,          DEC      02
   0,          DEC      01
   END         START
```

[image]

Comment: Paste your code so we can try it.  Otherwise, just try some things, many of these little assemblers are very picky, some don't like whitespace before the label, some give bad error messages.  Also, maybe see if you can cut it down to just one line that it complains about.  Also, marie has several tools, so you should indicate which one you're using.  Try another one like https://marie.js.org

Comment: I added the code, I am using Mariesim.jar if that helps.